# Trying to capture a price from a specific Bar

Tags: debugging

im new to thinkscript and programming in general. So this has been a slow and painful process for me !

Right now, im trying to pull the opening price from the bar where my script fires.

The basics are

`def trigger = masterconA and masterconA4h   and e and f and (a or b or c or d);`

`def Counter = if BarNumber() == 1 then 0 else if trigger then Counter[1] + 1 else Counter [1] ;`

`def stopline = Lowest(low, length = 3) - ATR() * atrmulti;`

Independently verified all variables associated with Entry are working.
Verified stop line is working correctly
Verified counter is working properly.
Verified that Addorder only fires when counter = 1 AND Trigger is true.

Expecting Entrypoint to be = to Open of bar when trigger is true and counter is 1
Expecting exitpoint to be = to stopline of bar when trigger is true and counter is 1

These are the variables in question

`def entrypoint = if trigger  and Counter == 1 then open else entrypoint == entrypoint [1];`

`def exitpoint =  if trigger  and Counter == 1 then stopline else exitpoint == exitpoint[1];`

Unfortunately neither variable seem to be holding any value.
Attempts to plot, or put the results in a Addlabel() or addchartbubble() all break the study/strategy

There is a failure of logic here somewhere and I just dont know where it is.
Code below.
Thanks !

`